# Multi-line UILabel not resizing text when using attributedText

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am trying to make a very custom UILabel. When `viewDidAppear` is called, the UILabel's `attributedText` property is set. **This UILabel needs to be 2 lines.** I have `minimumFontSize` set to 7 and `numberOfLines` set to 2 in storyboard.

Here is my code:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 8.0
        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Right

        let name = idea?.valueForKey("name") as! String
        let text = "You submitted your name " + name
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            attrString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12.00), range: NSMakeRange(0,attrString.length))
            attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            attrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(r: 84, g: 105, b: 121, a: 1.0), range: NSMakeRange(0, 3))
            attrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(r: 84, g: 105, b: 121, a: 1.0), range: NSMakeRange(attrString.length - name.characters.count, name.characters.count))

        submittedComment.attributedText = attrString
```

**ISSUE:** The newly set text for the UILabel is not resized to fit within the UILabel.

Am I missing something? It seems like every new major iOS update changes the way this occurs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**
There were two main errors I found:

1. It seems that setting the `lineSpacing` on an NSMutableAttributedString will hide some of the text. From what I've tested, it doesn't seem like the autoresizing feature of UILabel considers this when resizing.
2. My UILabel had a set width and height. The issue here was setting the height, which wasn't necessary in my case. Once I removed it, my `attributedText` was no longer hidden.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's enough to just layout the view again to consider the `lineSpacing`. For example in my case I had to do the following:

```swift
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: R.reuseIdentifier.descriptionCell, for: indexPath)!
cell.label.text = "Long text with multiple line breaks."
    + " In the nib the attributedText style including the paragaphStyle is configured"
    + " so just set the text here"
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
return cell
```

Comment: Haven't tried this after setting attributedText on UILabel, but that might work. Thank you for the response.